# LinearLayout UI not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm using Android 4.2 and have this issue on multiple mobile devices including Samsung S4 and Samsung Galaxy Note 2.

I have a LinearLayout that is nested in a HorizontalScrollView. I programmatically add ImageViews to the LinearLayout like so:

```
//in the actual code this list is handed in as an argument to the method that
//populates the layout
ArrayList<View> views;
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.theid);
//clear any existing views
layout.removeAllViews();
for (View v : views)
{
    layout.addView(v);
}
```

This is being run on the UI thread.

This works as expected **however** if I turn off the devices screen by doing it manually or letting it time out, then turn it back on, when I run the code that does this my LinearLayout's UI will no longer update to reflect the new Images in the view. When I debug I am finding that the code appears to be doing everything it should -  the Layout does indeed have the new views, I can look at them in the debugger, even click one programmatically and see the expected behaviour, the UI simply doesn't change.

I've tried calling `layout.invalidate()` to force a redraw but still don't see a change. Although interestingly enough if I start another activity, then hit back to bring up the activity these layouts live on things will start working as expected again.

I'm pretty stumped at this point. If anyone has seen behaviour like this before, or has any advice on things to try to fix it I would really appreciate it. Thanks much!

Comment: try to use ViewTreeObserver and On[Pre]DrawListener and see what happens

Comment: @pskink - I hooked up a ViewTreeObserver, I'm seeing onPreDraw firing multiple times when the above code is executed. Is there anything in particular you suggest I look for?

Comment: hmm, extend that LL and override its dispatchDraw, before calling super call canvas.drawColor(0xffff0000) and see what happens